# How to Calculate age using a year month column?

Tags: sql-server

I am tryign to get the age of a product by using a `YRMO (Year/Month Ex:201606)` column. I want to be able to have the product, Yrmo and age so:

```
 Product  | YrMo   | Age|
 A        | 201602 |  1 |
 A        | 201603 |  2 |
 B        | 201605 |  4 |
```

---

I used this method but wasn't able to get the results

```
 SELECT 
       Product      
     , YrMo
     , [Month_#]    =   DATEDIFF(MONTH,201601,YrMo) 

 FROM Table
```

When I used a datetype it returned consecutive months:

```
  [Month_#] =   DATEDIFF(MONTH,'1900-01-01',YrMo)
```

Instead.. Any tips on how to be able to get around this?

Comment: For "age" why are you comparing to Jan 2016 rather than the current date?

Comment: The 'Age' is the date difference between the Year month column and another date in order to identify consecutive months.

Answer (score 1):

Simple

```
SELECT  Product,
        YrMo,
        DATEDIFF(month,STUFF(YrMo,5,0,'-')+'-01','2016-01-01') as Age
FROM YourTable
```

Output:

```
Product YrMo    Age
A       201602  1
A       201603  2
B       201605  4
```

Comment: That works fine when I am calculating the month for the given year, but say I want to calculate months from 201501? then I would get :                   201601-201501 = 100 ? and not 12 months

Comment: That, make sense :) changed answer

Comment: for sql-server you do NOT NEED the dash, date literals in YYYYMMDD are in fact very safe to use i.e. `DATEDIFF(month,(YrMo+'01'),'20160101')`

Comment: @Swazzy did you check my edits? That should give you an age in months.

Comment: @gofr1 Yes , I tried it and it worked Thanks! its a little different but I will add it to the arsenal. Thanks again for your direction

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product, 
       yrmo, 
       [Month_#] = Datediff(month, Cast('1900-01-01' AS DATE), Cast( 
                   '20160101' AS DATE) 
                   ) 
FROM   table
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the date from inception (I assume that is year month column) or the date difference between another abstract date and the yrmo column?

Comment: Yes this is a Year month column and I wanted to get the date difference between it and an abstract date (1900-01-01), Thanks for helping me reword my question

Answer (score 1):

You are close with your query, but you can't just cast an int or 6-digit string to a date. Here's your query, modified:

```
select 
    Product      
    , YrMo
    , [Month_#] = datediff(month, cast(cast(201601 as varchar(11)) + '01' as date), cast(cast(YrMo as varchar(11)) + '01' as date))
from Products
```

Results:

```
Product  YrMo    Month_#
A        201602  1
A        201603  2
B        201605  4
```

Note that I'm casting ints to varchar and then appending '01' to make it a full date. Depending on the datatypes you're really using, you can probably make this prettier.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Product VARCHAR(1), YrMo INT,  Age INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
( 'A',         201602 ,  1) ,
( 'A' ,        201603 ,  2),
( 'B'  ,       201605 ,  4)


    SELECT      AGE, YRMO, 
                (YRMO / 100 * 12 +  YRMO % 100 ) - (201601 /100 *12 + 201601 % 100) AS  AGE
    FROM    @T
```